# In how many ways can $4$ different letters be posted in $6$ letter boxes?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can $4$ different letters be posted in $6$ letter boxes?

My Attempt:
 One letter box can take one letter. So for 4 letters we choose 4 boxes....

Can anyone give me a clear and easily understandable solution.?

Comment: Is it possible that more than one letter goes in a single box?

Comment: This isn't clear.  Are the letters distinguishable?  Are the letter boxes? Your attempt asserts that "one letter box can take one letter."  is that something we are meant to assume?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs,I guess no..

Comment: Why would you guess that?  Have you ever seen a letter box that can only take one letter?

Comment: To stress:  it matter if the letters are distinguishable or not.  If they aren't (and if you want to stick to your one letter per box assumption) then the answer is $\binom 64$.  If they are (and you want your assumption) then the answer is $6\times 5\times 4\times 3$.  Other answers are possible, according to the assumptions you make.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we can have more than one letter in a given box, then we just count the number of ways to choose one of six boxes, four times in a row:

$$6\times 6\times 6\times 6 = 6^4=1296$$

---

If each box can hold at most one letter, then we begin, as you said, by counting the number of ways to choose $4$ of $6$ boxes: $\binom64=\frac{6!}{4!2!}=15$, we can multiply this by the number of orders in which $4$ letters can go into the four chosen boxes: $4!=24$. Thus:

$$\binom64\times 4!=15\times 24=360$$

---

Both of these solutions assume that the four letters are different. If the letters are indistinguishable, then we have a different counting problem.

Suppose the letters are all the same, and a mailbox can hold more than one. Then, we consider the number of ways to arrange $5$ "bars" and $4$ "stars", where the bars represent separations between adjacent boxes, and stars represent letters. For example:

$$\,\,**\,\,|\,\,*\,\,|\,\,\,\,|\,\,\,\,|\,\,*\,\,|\,\,\,\,$$

would represent two letters in the first box, one in the second, and one in the fifth.

This is a total of $9$ symbols, and they can be arranged as many ways as there are to decide which $4$ of the nine should be "stars":

$$\binom94=\frac{9!}{4!5!}=126$$

---

Finally, if the boxes can hold at most one letter each, but the letters are indistinguishable, then the answer is simply:

$$\binom64=15$$

Comment: I've been trying to learn combinatorics and this is one of the most helpful answers I've ever seen. I don't fully grasp it yet, but I love the way you broke down the individual cases, going from the most possible ways to the least. Thank you thank you thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the letters are distinguishable (i.e. putting letters 1,2 into the first box and letters 3,4 into the second is counted separately from putting letters 3,4 into the first box and letters 1,2 into the second).  I also assume that multiple letters can be put into the same box.

For each letter, we much choose a box.  These are 4 independently made choices, for which there are $6$ options.  The total number of possibilities is therefore
$$
6^4 = 1296
$$